# Download of source of htmlunit-core-js-2.31.jar

Tags: java, htmlunit

Where/how can I download the source code for htmlunit-core-js-2.31.jar ? So far I found only the jar-file without source ...

Thanks

PS: found [this](https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=htmlunit-core-js&g=net.sourceforge.htmlunit&v=2.31&downloadable=1) but have to download each file separatly

Comment: Just read the docs: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html

Comment: @Matteo: same as GitHub: no source for the corejs included, e.g. net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`htmlunit-core-js` is, as reported on the [HtmlUnit Documentation](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html) for developer page (at the very bottom), a fork of `htmlunit-rhino` and the source code you are searching for is available [here on Github](https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-rhino-fork), the main repository for the project. There is also a test package that has on Github the name of `htmlunit-core-js`, if you want to test your compiled version, here.

Another link is [here](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22htmlunit-core-js%22), on Maven Central, you have to click on `sources.jar` to download the source code you are searching for, and unzip the `jar` file with a compression utility.